# jQuery: parse a <section> from html

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to parse a `<section>` from html on jQuery, depending on the value the user entered (#term) in the form with the following code:

HTML:

```
     <section id="fetch">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name here" id="term" />
         <button id="search">ENTER</button>
     </section>

     <section id="content">
        <div id = "figures">
            <script>
            </script>
        </div>

        <div id ="name">
            <div id = "nameBox">
            </div>
            <div id = "nameText">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id = "message">        
            <div id = "messageBox">
            </div>
            <div id = "messageText">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#term').focus(function(){
   var full = $("#content").has("<section>").length ? true : false; 

  if(full == false){
     $('#content').empty();
  }
});
```

I wonder if there is anything wrong with the syntax cos I keep having console error of

> TypeError: a is undefined

It would be very nice if someone could identify my problem to me.

Furthermore, you might want to have a look at the fiddle for the full code I created [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/rokvowjv/).

Comment: Since you don't use a variable called `a` in the code you've shared, the problem must be coming from elsewhere.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `a` in the error message is coming from the minified version of jQuery, its cause is that you're trying to call `$.each` with `undefined` as the first parameter.

```
// getName does not exist - it is undefined!
var getName = $.each(getName, function (content, json) {
    console.log(json.name);
    console.log(getName[content].id);
});
```

In any case, `$.each` does not explicitly define a return value, so there's a second (potential) error in your code.

This has nothing to do with how you're detecting the existance of `section` elements, that should be as easy as:

```
var full = $("#content").find("section").length > 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you're trying to find out whether or not the 'section' exists.

In that case, you should be able to write this.

```
var full = $("#content section").length
```

The correct selector for an html tag, is the tag itself, without the angle brackets. The same way `$(div)` selects all the divs.

Also, there is no need to add the `? false : true` part. If the element does not exist, the length will evaluate to 0, which is equivalent to false.

Answer (score 2):

As per jQuery [.has](https://api.jquery.com/has/) method defination:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant
>   that matches the selector or DOM element.

Try `var full = $("section[id=content]").length ? true : false;` instead of `var full = $("#content").has("<section>").length ? true : false;`.

**NOTE:** `$("#content").has("<section>")` will search `section` element inside `#content`, which is always false.

Hope this will helps.